# How to check if HttpRequest is coming from WebView?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webview, windows-runtime, user-agent

I have a WinRT app that opens a WebView to my MVC Web Application.

I want to serve a special layout for this particular browser, using MVC Browser Specific View. The reason for this is because the view port is going to be a lot smaller than "normal"

What would be the best way to configure this? I checked the User Agent string and it's very generic and doesn't tell me much:

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; Touch; WebView/1.0)"
```

Is there a way I can create a condition to check for the WebView?

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("WinRTWebView")
{
    ContextCondition = (context => ???WHAT BOOLEAN LOGIC SHOULD GO HERE???)
});
```

I may also need to create special user agent on my webview accordingly if anyone knows how to do that... I checked the API on MSDN and nothing obvious came up.

Answer (score 0):

Since the User Agent is not providing anything you can use, I can think of two other options:

1. Include a parameter in the URL you are providing to the WebView: `?client=winrt`

Then just use the presence of that parameter to determine which view to display.

1. Second option would be to use responsive design so that you don't need to check the User Agent, but instead adapt the view based on the viewport size. This approach would not allow you to use different views. And instead just have one view that is served and use CSS to position items differently.